# Keyboard shortcuts starting with Alt don't work in VS

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard

Keyboard shortcuts which start with <kbd>Alt</kbd> (such as *Peek Definition* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) stopped working on Visual Studio 2015.
When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, those underscores appear under menu items (which is default behavior of windows) as shown on image

[image]

Other keyboard shortcuts such as <kbd>F5</kbd>, and all the ones starting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are working properly.
I've found a lot of answers about keyboard shortcut conflicts after installing ReSharper,  but I haven't installed it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you added any other extensions other than Resharper that you think might have cause the problem?

Comment: @HamzaAnis, no, I haven't

Comment: Have you checked the keybindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long troubleshoting and googling I've combined multiple things and it worked:

1. Updated the Visual Studio
2. Resetted keyboard layout with following steps:
   2.1. Make sure you have no additional keyboard and displays connected (this could be optional step, but without this the solution was not
   working for me)
   2.2. From menu open "Tools" and select "Options"
   2.3. From left side select "Environment" and click on "Keyboard"
   2.4. Change the mapping scheme to "Default"
   2.5. Click on "Reset" (You'll be promted something then click on "Yes") and OK
   2.6. And now restart the application
   [image]
3. Also by the way installed ReSharper and uninstalled (this also plays keyboard shortcuts of Visual Studio) and retried second step

Answer (score 15):

In my case it was Nvidia's "In-Game Overlay". In case you are running this software, try disabling this in the "Geforce Experience".

The image below shows where to do this:
[image]

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out wondering what was stealing my shortcut keys in various IDE's. Turning that off fixed it for me too.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress Coderush overrides some of the Alt key bindings which prevent Visual Studio using them (ie: Alt Left & Right).

They can be disabled selectively via Extensions -> CodeRush -> Options -> IDE -> Shortcuts -> untick Enabled on right.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that it's due to GeForce Experience. Of course, not exactly GeForce Experience's fault since it's meant for gamers. After disabling the In-game overlay under Options (wheel), General, In-game Overlay, alt+F7 worked immediately.